# I am trying to draw a point from the line with specific cordinates using the lines Spatial Reference but points are not exact where the line exist?

Tags: arcpy

```
SR = arcpy.Describe(inFC_line).spatialReference
```

I have my line list

```
line_list = [[469750.87399999984, 233710.21829999983], [469751.4919999996, 233710.39699999988], [469751.28199999966, 233710.97399999946], [469750.4979999997, 233711.73299999908], [469750.0284000002, 233713.38040000014], [469747.6469999999, 233721.73399999924], [469747.56900000013, 233721.86700000055], [469747.19070000015, 233721.87879999913], [469745.30399999954, 233721.93799999915], [469745.14719999954, 233721.90839999914], [469744.01410000026, 233721.6947000008], [469741.70969999954, 233721.25999999978], [469740.9073999999, 233721.10869999975], [469740.19959999993, 233720.9751999993], [469736.4210999999, 233720.26249999925], [469735.43200000003, 233720.07599999942], [469734.5290000001, 233721.35899999924], [469734.3426000001, 233721.44439999945], [469731.8223000001, 233722.59820000082], [469727.7823999999, 233724.44769999944], [469724.9115000004, 233725.7620000001], [469718.6266000001, 233728.63929999992], [469715.29399999976, 233730.1649999991], [469712.2810000004, 233731.19099999964], [469706.8761999998, 233733.5231999997], [469699.7625000002, 233736.59300000034], [469692.6635999996, 233739.65630000085], [469687.24399999995, 233741.99499999918], [469686.7132000001, 233741.07630000077]]
```

and my point list is

```
point_list = [[469750.87399999984, 233710.21829999983], [469751.4919999996, 233710.39699999988], [469751.28199999966, 233710.97399999946], [469750.4979999997, 233711.73299999908], [469750.0284000002, 233713.38040000014], [469747.6469999999, 233721.73399999924], [469747.56900000013, 233721.86700000055], [469747.19070000015, 233721.87879999913], [469745.30399999954, 233721.93799999915], [469745.14719999954, 233721.90839999914], [469744.01410000026, 233721.6947000008], [469741.70969999954, 233721.25999999978], [469740.9073999999, 233721.10869999975], [469740.19959999993, 233720.9751999993], [469736.4210999999, 233720.26249999925], [469735.43200000003, 233720.07599999942], [469734.5290000001, 233721.35899999924], [469734.3426000001, 233721.44439999945], [469731.8223000001, 233722.59820000082], [469727.7823999999, 233724.44769999944], [469724.9115000004, 233725.7620000001], [469718.6266000001, 233728.63929999992], [469715.29399999976, 233730.1649999991], [469712.2810000004, 233731.19099999964], [469706.8761999998, 233733.5231999997], [469699.7625000002, 233736.59300000034], [469692.6635999996, 233739.65630000085], [469687.24399999995, 233741.99499999918], [469686.7132000001, 233741.07630000077]]
```

I am using the below codes to draw the point using arcpy:-

```
arr = numpy.array(point_list,numpy.dtype([('XY', '<f8', 2)]))

arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(arr, geoDB + "/linestring_" + str(cable_used), ['XY'], SR)
```

[image]

As I am using the geometry and spatial reference to draw the point for the selected line but it is not at the exact geometry as line placed.

What would be the mistakes that I am doing here?

Comment: What is your image trying to show and where did these coordinates come from? Edit your question to include this information, don't 2 write it into the comments.

Comment: How big is the difference to what you expect? Floating point calculations are inaccurate, maybe you should reduce the precision to some reasonable level https://rapidlasso.com/2019/05/06/how-many-decimal-digits-for-storing-longitude-latitude/ https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/2170:_Coordinate_Precision

Comment: You can add a vertex to the line geometry at the desired location, then the extract point will be exactly on the line. Else don't check for geometry intersections but rather for points within a close distance of the line geometry